# how to restore windows 7 without losing data

Tags: data-recovery

I actually was testing something and accidentally changed the serial number of my window 7 64 bit. when that happened, the windows shutdown and every time I turn it on, it gives me some error message and windows can;t start at all... The error message is that there is an error in the system. so the system asks to check all times. when I get finished with the check, the windows restart and again do the same check on and on. unfortunately, I don't have a back up DVD and a recovery CD. There is an option though sometimes show up, which is an option stating that it can re-do the windows to the factory settings, but I'm scared that all my data and other software will be gone if I do that...

any idea how to resolve this weird situation??

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try and do a start up repair from the pre load windows boot menu by hitting F8 on start up. failing that i would try a Repair Upgrade which will reset a lot of things in the OS but keep most of the data intact.

I realize you mention you do not have a backup DVD or a recovery CD, but if you had a **installation/upgrade DVD/CD** you can do a repair upgrade on top of your existing installation.

Guide for doing a repair install:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

EDIT: to address the concern of resetting your product key, you can do this by loading into safe mode via F8 on boot, you want to hit it just before the windows loading screen comes up.

running cmd as administrator and typing: slmgr.vbs -ipk 
To activate windows after changing the key, type: slmgr.vbs -ato

I assume this command may also work from the recovery console option during boot up from an install media.

Comment: Thanks @Walter. I will try that and see if it helps. Be back when I finish trying...

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. The F8 button doesn't work and don't know why. A blue screen show up displaying a loading icon then a check by windows itself starts automatically and take forever to finish...

Comment: BTW, resting the window to the factory settings would cause deleting all my files in this case?? is that true??

Comment: I'm sure it depends on what the specific process was setup to do, could differ based on vendor, but by the name "factory settings" it would be safe to assume it could delete everything to revert it back to the way it came from the factory.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but is there a way how I can force the PC to go on dos mode so I can change the serial from there?? Thanks

Comment: BTW, is it OK to install another version of windows 7 on the current one? I mean my brother has the same window 7 and I'm wondering if I can use that one or not??

Comment: i edited my post to include options for changing the key, i would only use a disk that is for the same version of windows 7 that you have installed, i.e., home premium, as long as that is the same it is ok to use his disk.

Comment: Thanks @Walter. The only problem I have now getting the option commends screen using F8. The F8 button doesn't work at it. If this issue is solved. I get I'm close to the final solution in this case... I need a solution for F8 issue now. will search around as well to find out.

Comment: unfortunately, the F8 thing doesn't work at all. Luckily now I have DVD for recovery, but still doesn't do much. I reach the prompt commend, but with X:/ extension. I tried to do the changing key method you posted above, but it didn't work. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is give if to the service center or upgrade d OS...I had the same problem...n my windows start up went from 1min 27 secs to 11mins 33 seconds..I did a system restore but still the problems persisted...so i upgraded to windows 8 pro n guess wat?? Its smooth as butter... only thing is that da OS 8 dosnt support much oftwares or games but hey,i dnt need to wait 11mins to view a document...Lol..All da best...